# How do I pass a mysql record ID from one page to another?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a search form that when you click on the more info link for a record will open a new window for that record to display additional information and I use `<a href=more_info.php?id=$rows[id]>`to pass the id to the next page and that works great.

On that next page I have a button that pops up a small browser window using this `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('signature_pad.html', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=200'); return false;">` this windows pops up with a signature pad.

What I need to do is pass that record ID from the second window to the popup window so when the customer signs the signature pad their signature is posted into the correct record.

so here is the code for the 2nd and popup pages: (I only posted the code for the button section of the 2nd page to save space as the code for that page is fairly long and only the button portion pertains to this question)

```
<table class="auto-style16" style="width: 615px; height: 28px;">
<td style="width: 435px; height: 22px;" class="auto-style7">
**<a href="#" onclick="window.open('signature_pad.php', 'newwindow', 'width=500,   height=200');    return false;"><input type="button" value="Get Signature" /></a>**
```

And the popup window

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Signature Pad</title>

<!-- The Signature Pad -->
<script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="signature-pad.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<fieldset style="width: 435px">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="signaturePad" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; height: 55px; width: 400px;"></div>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <button id="clearSig" type="button">Clear Signature</button>&nbsp;
    <button id="saveSig" type="button">Save Signature</button>
    <div id="imgData"></div>
    <br/>
    </fieldset>
</center>
<div id="debug"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you add the id to `signature_pag.php` like you did for the `more_info.php` ?

Comment: @Prix I tried that, it didn't work!

Comment: What exactly did not work for you ? It doesn't open the new window ? The query doesn't go to the new window ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @Prix the code as it is works fine, I need to pass the record id to the popup window. using <a href=signature_pad.php?id=$rows[id]> on the button of the second page for the popup window doesn't pass the id to the popup.

Comment: @Prix when the button is pressed and the popup window appears this is what is in the address bar signature_pad.php?id=$rows[id]

Comment: Can you show me the relevant piece of your php code that is creating the window.open ?

Comment: @Prix it's already posted in the original question and in the first section of code.

Comment: Nope I meant the PHP code not HTML, you are using that portion of HTML within a PHP code right ? And you also said when you use the above it prints out the URL as `signature_pad.php?id=$rows[id]` which leads me to believe you're doing something wrong at your PHP code.

Comment: @Prix There are only 2 pages involved in the passing of the id and the code for both of them is displayed. I don't know what else you are looking for there is no php code that creates the popup windows it's one line of html as an " a href" before the button.

Comment: I don't get you, you're calling the pages/links `.php` but you're not using PHP so how do you expect the variables to pass down to other pages ? If you're using PHP on the first page where you grab all the records and place it like you have above mentioned `more_info.php?id=$rows[id]` where `$rows[id]` do become an ID since you're using PHP for it, for the next page all you need is to use `$_GET` and same goes for your signature page. Otherwise this won't work with sessions either since you're not using any PHP at all as suggested on the other reply.

Comment: @Prix you're making this more complicated than it is more_info.php is an html form with php used to populate the input boxes, thus the php extension. I don't need to post the entire form as the entire form doesn't pertain to the question only the button referenceing the popup window. The popup window is all html but can easily be changed to php if that's what is required to get the id to pass. The php extension was added to the signature_pad form when It was suggested to use sessions which I decided not to use for this purpose. So the form is still named with a php extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the doesn't work page you have:

more_info.php

```
<p>I have some text here and am just a HTML page saved as .php</p>
<table class="auto-style16" style="width: 615px; height: 28px;">
<td style="width: 435px; height: 22px;" class="auto-style7">
**<a href="#" onclick="window.open('signature_pad.php?id=$rows[id]', 'newwindow', 'width=500,   height=200');    return false;"><input type="button" value="Get Signature" /></a>**
```

This is how it should be:

more_info.php

```
<?php
$myId = $_GET['id'];
?>
<p>I have some text here and am a HTML with PHP page saved as .php</p>
<table class="auto-style16" style="width: 615px; height: 28px;">
<td style="width: 435px; height: 22px;" class="auto-style7">
**<a href="#" onclick="window.open('signature_pad.php?id=<?php echo $myId; ?>', 'newwindow', 'width=500,   height=200');    return false;"><input type="button" value="Get Signature" /></a>**
```

On my above example, I am making use of php for 2 things, first I received the query string id and save it into my variable `$myId` then I print the variable to the HTML location it should for the window.open. You can also print the `$_GET` directly but I prefer not to in case I need to further do things to the variable like sanitization, etc.

[More information on `$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Prix much better that explanation is more helpful I knew I needed to add something after the form name but didn't even think to put it between php tags. Thank you!

Comment: That's why I asked you the relevant code, since you said you didn't have one that's what I believe the issue was :)

Comment: Sorry my bad, I actually already had $id=$_GET[id]; at the very top of the page, I didn't think to use the php tags after page extension. Thank you it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

To carry a variable across your PHP application you can use either GET /  POST (hidden option) or PHP Session, or use your database

Since you need to save variables across your web app, you have to incorporte sessions (with or w/o database).

On top of each page add this:
`session_start();` and this will allow your web app server track each user.

Then assign any vars to session `$_SESSION['user']='Bob';`

Then, when you get familiar with sessions, you can just keep track of user id and keep the rest in the database

Check [this article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472581/PHP-Tutorial-Sessions.htm) and go from there

Comment: so would I do something like this at the top of my page? $id=$_POST['id']; and add a hidden field?

Comment: If you have many variables, you can have a table in your database, and have fields: `userid`, `variables_array`. Then add all variables to `variables_array` as `var_name,var_value;var_name2,var_value;` etc. And then parse those variables according to the user id (from the session) from the database on each page load

Comment: I'm fairly new to php Andrew so you're explanation is a bit over my head. I kind of understand enough to research what you've suggested. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Andrew thanks for your help, This seems to have gotten too complicated for what I want to do so I think I will just move the signature pad into the main form until I can figure this out. Thanks for your help!